# MySQL query to find all URLs that are substring of other URLs

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL field `URL` of type Varchar.

Is it possible with *one* MySQL query to return *all* records where the string value `URL` is a substring of another record `URL` value, and display both the substrings and full strings records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join the table with itself. Something like:

```
SELECT t1.URL, t2.URL AS SUBURL
FROM mytable t1, mytable t2
WHERE INSTR(t1.URL, t2.URL) > 0
AND t1.ID < t2.ID
```

Note that the query has N^2 complexity and string matching is slow. Expect terrible performance on large tables.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer is "Yes", using the [INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) or LOCATE() functions. But it depends on how your URLS are stored.  Things like "http://", subdomains, and such can give you many false positives or false negatives. Not false in the sense that INSTR() is broken, but false in the sense that it won't do what you might want it to.

Comment: I don't mind false positives as long as I get the true positives. I would be interested to see how you would write the query using LOCATE().

Comment: LOCATE() and INSTR() work essentially the same. The order of arguments is different, and LOCATE() lets you specify a starting position, which probably doesn't matter in your case. (But we haven't seen any of your data.) See Elad's use of INSTR().